# SSRS Report does not open and throws an Error - The RDL structure of the tablix named 'tablix 1' is invalid

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWwQr.png)

When I try to open the report, it thrown an error message - *The RDL structure of the tablix named 'tablix 1' is invalid*. I tried to Add Totals for the group and probably that messed up. However, when I tried to add, it just crashed and after that when I try to open, it is showing this error. Please help!

Comment: Can you not just restore the previous version from source control or backup or, if you have not published the report to the SSRS server yet, you can download the existing RDL directly from the SSRS server and overwrite your development copy

Answer (score 0):

If a report is corrupted or otherwise unable to open because of an object and you do not have a previous version, the RDL can be opened as XML so the object can be removed.

In Visual Studio, the VIEW menu has a Code selection that will show the report as XML. You could also use an XML editor like Notepad++.

Find the object that is causing the error and select the XML for the entire object and delete the lines from `< Tablix Name="Tablix1">` to `</Tablix>`.

This will remove the tablix from the RDL file so that it should now be able to be opened.

[image]